An operator Hermitian in one space and Unitary "across" two spaces!
I am a physics student with humble background in Mathematics. I have the following understanding of Hermitian and Unitary matrices:
$$
A = A^\dagger \implies {\rm A~is~Hermitian}\qquad {\rm and }\qquad 
A A^\dagger = A^\dagger A \implies {\rm A~is~Unitary}
$$
where $\dagger$ is denotes the combined operation of complex-conjugation and transposition. Now I am puzzled by the following statements in this (freely available) article (page no. 4):

$\dots \rho:= \sqrt{\eta}$ acts as Hermitian operator in $\mathcal{H}$
$\rho$ defines a unitary operator mapping $\mathcal{H}_{\eta} \to \mathcal{H}$

My question: If $\rho$ is Hermitian as well as unitary i.e. $\rho = \rho^\dagger$ as well as $\rho^\dagger = \rho^{-1}$, then $\rho^\dagger \rho = \rho^2 = \mathbb{1}$ must be an identity operator. But note that $\rho^2 := \eta$ which is necessarily  a non-identity operator as per the article.

Note that this is talking about different spaces - $\rho$ is Hermitian regarded as an operator from $\mathcal{H}$ to $\mathcal{H}$, and is unitary regarded as an operator from $\mathcal{H}_\eta$ to $\mathcal{H}$. These are very much different things. $\rho$ is never simultaneously a Hermitian operator and a unitary, so no contradictions arise.

@DavidGao, thanks for your comment. At what point can I say that $\rho^\dagger = \rho^{-1}$? For example, in footnote $3$ on the same page (no. $4$), we have $H = \rho^{-1} h \rho$ s.t. $\rho$ is mapping $H \in \mathcal{H}_{\eta}$ to $h \in \mathcal{H}$, can I write instead $H = \rho^{\dagger} h \rho$? Would it mean the same thing as $H = \rho^{-1} h \rho$?

First of all, $H$ is an operator acting on $\mathcal{H}$, not an element of $\mathcal{H}$. The same for $h$. Now, whether you can write $H = \rho^\dagger h\rho$ depends on what you meant by $\dagger$. Recall that the definition of $\dagger$ depends on the inner product, so $\rho^\dagger$ is different depending whether you regard $\rho$ as an operator from $\mathcal{H}$ to $\mathcal{H}$, or an operator from $\mathcal{H}_\eta$ to $\mathcal{H}$. In the former case, no, you can’t write $H = \rho^\dagger h\rho$. In the latter case, yes, you can, as $\rho^\dagger = \rho^{-1}$ in that case.

(Of course, in the latter case, you would be regarding $H$ as an operator from $\mathcal{H}\eta$ to $\mathcal{H}\eta$, instead of from $\mathcal{H}$ to $\mathcal{H}$, as in the former case.)

Wait...but $H$ is anyway defined from $\mathcal{H}{\eta} \to \mathcal{H}{\eta}$   whether we write it as $H = \rho^{-1} h \rho$ or $H = \rho^\dagger h \rho$. It is $h$ which is acts $\mathcal{H} \to \mathcal{H}$, right?

Not really. The footnote meant $H$ as an operator on $\mathcal{H}$, not on $\mathcal{H}\eta$. $H$, an operator defined on $\mathcal{H}$, is called quasi-Hermitian if there is a positive-definite $\rho$ (which is positive-definite as an operator on $\mathcal{H}$) and a Hermitian operator $h$ on $\mathcal{H}$ s.t. $H = \rho^{-1}h\rho$. All of these have nothing to do with $\mathcal{H}\eta$. But, if $H$ happens to be quasi-Hermitian, then you can define $\eta$ s.t. $\rho$, if now regarded as an operator from $\mathcal{H}_\eta$ to $\mathcal{H}$, is a unitary; and $H$, if now regarded as an…

… operator on $\mathcal{H}\eta$, is Hermitian. $H = \rho^{-1}h\rho$ is true whether you regard $H$ as defined on $\mathcal{H}\eta$ (in which case $\rho$ has to be regarded as from $\mathcal{H}\eta$ to $\mathcal{H}$), or as defined on $\mathcal{H}$ (in which case $\rho$ has to be regarded as from $\mathcal{H}$ to $\mathcal{H}$). That $H = \rho^\dagger h\rho$ is only true when $H$ is regarded as defined on $\mathcal{H}\eta$ (in which case, again, $\rho$ has to be regarded as from $\mathcal{H}_\eta$ to $\mathcal{H}$).
